# date-fns convert string date format 'MMM-DD-YYYY' into Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

How can I convert using **date-fns** the following string into Date?

`Jul-30-2021` (format MMM-DD-YYYY).

Using **momentjs** I can convert it using:

```js
moment('Jul-30-2021', 'MMM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: What is the input & expected output?

Comment: input: Jul-30-2021
output: Date object with the date Jul-30-2021 and 00:00:00 time or current time

Comment: Try this `new Date('Jul-30-2021').toISOString()` after that you can use format from Date-fns to convert to any format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<script type="module">
  import { format } from 'https://esm.run/date-fns'

  const date = new Date('Jul-30-2021');

  console.log(date);

  console.log(format(date, 'MMM-dd-yyyy, mm:HH:ss'));
</script>
```

Now you can apply the date-fns `format(date, 'MMM-dd-yyyy')`

Comment: the result is 2021-07-29T22:00:00.000Z, which is wrong

Comment: Yes, you need to apply the format operator, check the last line. You can change it according to your needs.

Comment: @StefanoBorzì check the snippet I updated it, it now uses date fns. If that solved your issue please mark the question as solved, if not let me know I will update the answer.

Comment: I tried to run this `format(new Date('Jul-30-2021'), 'mmm-dd-yyyy')` but I get 000-30-2021

Comment: Just now I added the example with date fns. It should be MMM for date mmm is for time.

Comment: yes, you commented it 10 seconds before my comment xD

Man, I like your solution, thank you!

Comment: `new Date('Jul-30-2021')` this does not work on firefox :(, I will use the other solution probably

Comment: As per this it should work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I've downloaded firefox and tried `new Date('Aug-30-2021')`, it does not work

Answer (score 5):

this way :

```js
const setDateMDY = dteSTR => 
  {
  let [m,d,y] = dteSTR.split('-')
  return new Date(`${m} ${d}, ${y} 00:00:00`)
  }

let  date1 = setDateMDY('Jul-30-2021')

console.log( date1.toLocaleString() )
```